# Flutter some exceptions are not being handled / caught

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, try-catch

Some Exceptions slips past error handling. It doesn't enter any of my exception handling, Why?

This is the second time it happens on different occasions, and still don't know how to fix the first instance.

```
try {
        ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) async {

        }).catchError((e) {
        var test = e;
        });
      } on Exception catch (ex) {
        var test = ex;
      } catch (e) {
        var test = e;
      }
```

[image]

Comment: It should go to 105 once you click on 'Step Over' in debugger

Comment: O.o Oh yea... You're right. Thanks. Add it as an answer, and i'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have options like `step over` and `step into` etc..in the debugger..

When an exception occurs and it shows an error..like you showed in the image..press the `step over` button which will take you to the catch block..

Hope it answers your question..

Answer (score 1):

The given Exception of PlatformException(...,null) occurs when few apis does not work for current platform you are working on.Try using another platforms too.For suppose In my case firebase_core not working for linux.But working for another platforms.